как сделать так что бы соощение в aiogram2 отправилось 1 раз в определенное время?
я пытался сделать напоминание о чем либо, но нашел информацию только как сделать так что бы бот каждый день условно в 17:55 присылал текст, мне же нужно что бы он один раз прислал и забыл о этой задаче и напоминал про другие
использовал aioschedule
не знаю что делать, помогите

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=aioschedule

@ИванРемнев   использовал aioschedule.
А как Вы использовали aioschedule, пример кода, что и как пытались реализовать?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
